# How I can add IP Address From start to end to Database?

Tags: php, ip-address, ipv4

I want to add IP address from start to end to database such as

```
IP Address (Start) 192.168.0.0
IP Address (End) 192.168.0.10
```

So it should add to database like

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
192.168.0.7
192.168.0.8
192.168.0.9
192.168.0.10
```

Thanks so much I have no idea.

Comment: Writing code would be a good start... We're here to help, not do your job for you. Here's a hint: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Can you give us more info on why are you doing this?

Comment: @MarcB You see my post? "I have no idea" I can do it if i know the idea or way to it if i can do it i will not come here to ask I tired to find, do, everything but not success.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Comment: @BadHorsie I used PHP with MySQL

Comment: Hint: If you have a range that spreads acroll multiple octets, converting to and from a numeric IP was the easiest way  when I did this a while back (using http://php.net/ip2long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, it will take care if the range spreads across octets

```
$start = '192.168.0.1';
$end = '192.168.1.255';

$startint = ip2long($start);
$endint = ip2long($end);

while ($startint <= $endint) {
 echo long2ip($startint++); // replace echo with your DB insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = '192.168.0.';
$x = 1;
while($x < 11)
{
echo $start.$x."<br>"; // create your code to add to table
    $x++;
}
```

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g9a4-qxfy

Comment: Code produces invalid IP addresses, if x >= 245

Comment: why don't you use a for loop?

Comment: Yes, but the OP said he wanted to stiop at 10.

Comment: To be a word stickler: OP implied he wanted 2 IPs as variables

Comment: Thank you for your observation Christian. The code I provided produces his desired results. He is free to expand on it.